# Prestashop how to customize theme

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have bought leo_chopin theme (because client asked for it). My question is how to customize a theme from html/php/css editor and not from admin panel (it's too constricting). I wouldn't hardcode, but use hooks. This is the first time I'm using Prestashop and that style of programing... For example, where to call my own header.tpl, footer.tpl, content.tpl?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `your_site_folder/themes/leo_chopin/` and you will find `header.tpl`, `footer.tpl`.
You can modify these templates there or make a copy of a theme into another folder and modify it.

All content between header and footer depends on a page `controller`. All controllers for the front are in a folder `your_site_folder/controllers/front/`. `ProductController.php` is for product pages, CategoryController.php is for category pages, IndexController.php is for the home page etc.

You can find more in Prestashop documentation: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Laying+the+Theme's+Foundations.